# failed to open stream: Invalid argument - php:copy

Tags: php, file, csv, copy

```
$files=file('big_files.csv');

$source = "M:\\xampp\\htdocs\\media_old\\thumbs\\";
$destination = "M:\\xampp\\htdocs\\media\\";

// To check the number of files 
echo count($files).'<br>';

//Just to make sure path variables are right
echo $source.'</br>';
echo $destination.'</br>';

foreach($files as $file) {

$orgfile=$source.$file;
echo 'Source is '.$orgfile.'</br>';
$newfile=$destination.$file;
echo 'Destination is '.$newfile;

if (!copy($orgfile, $newfile)) {
echo "failed to copy $file...</br>";
}
 echo "<b>Done</b> </br>";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Source is M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\1323442022d41e3-big-1.jpg 
Destination is M:\xampp\htdocs\media\1323442022d41e3-big-1.jpg 
Warning: copy(M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\1323442022d41e3-big-1.jpg ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in M:\xampp\htdocs\cvsprint.php on line 17
```

failed to copy 1323442022d41e3-big-1.jpg ...
    Done

```
Source is M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\132328900923a0b-big-2.jpg 
Destination is M:\xampp\htdocs\media\132328900923a0b-big-2.jpg 
Warning: copy(M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\132328900923a0b-big-2.jpg ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in M:\xampp\htdocs\cvsprint.php on line 17
```

failed to copy 132328900923a0b-big-2.jpg ...
    Done

```
Source is M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\132328935409b14-big-1.jpg 
Destination is M:\xampp\htdocs\media\132328935409b14-big-1.jpg 
Warning: copy(M:\xampp\htdocs\media_old\thumbs\132328935409b14-big-1.jpg ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in M:\xampp\htdocs\cvsprint.php on line 17
```

failed to copy 132328935409b14-big-1.jpg ...
    Done

So I call this thru xampp and keep getting that error.  I though because it is windoz it needs to be the absolute path, but trying it that way and relative both don't work nor does forward slashes either way.  I threw in some echos to see what it was trying to copy.  The files are all there if I cut and past them into windows explorer it pops them up in preview.

Background: I have a directory with 6 versions of files and they are formatted like filename-big-x.jpg.  I want to only move the relevant files that I am still using to a new directory.  They are all different versions so I did a database dump of the file names. Now I have a csv file that only has the file names as individual lines.  So now I want to read that file and copy the files I want to keep to a new directory.

Comment: Are you sure the M:\xampp\htdocs\media\ folder exists?

Comment: Yes, as I said I have other files in there and double checked everything.

Comment: what about rename() function?